# How to show source code sun.misc.vm within Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to read deeper into the way Threads return their current state. I am able to ctrl-click on getState(), which shows me the source code of Thread.class. However, ctrl-clicking on sun.misc.VM.toThreadState gives me "source not found".

My source attachment configuration is pointing towards jdk1.8.0_111/src.zip.

I tried to find the sun.misc.VM source in my workspace but I don't see it. Is it within the JRE System Library that resides in the same folder as my package? I have found the code online, but how can I make it such that I can ctrl-click and view it immediately? And how does Java get the sun.misc.VM source code if it's not inside src.zip?

Comment: Javac does not need source code, class files are good for compiling and running a Java class.

Comment: which version of jdk installed on your machine ?